# How to extract value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Using node.js 6.10

```
console.log("returned data1 " + body);
// returns: returned data1 "{'response' : 'Not latest version of file, update not performed'}"
```

I want to extract the `Not latest version of file, update not performed` and place it into the valueReturned var. I have tried

```
    var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
            var valueReturned = jsonBody["response"];
            console.log("logs: " + valueReturned);
// returns: logs: undefined
```

does anyone know where I am going wrong?

ThankYous

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You should fix whatever returns `body` such that it returns valid JSON format such that you can then parse it automatically. At the moment it kind of looks like an object string wrapped with `"` on each end.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(jsonBody)`? Do you get the expected object printout? @CertainPerformance note that might just be OP copying the response wrong, as if it was in fact invalid JSON text the `JSON.parse()` call would fail with an `unexpected token` error

Comment: As was said it needs to return valid JSON. Just to clarify valid JSON for that would be { "response": "Not latest version of file, update not performed" } . Changing single quotes to double. You can check for valid JSON at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BradenBrown your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid JSON string to parse JSON.

```js
let body = "{ \"response\" : \"Not latest version of file, update not performed\"}";
let jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
let valueReturned = jsonBody.response;
console.log("logs: " + valueReturned);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **body** is not a valid JSON format. The key and value should be wrapped in a double quotes("). Otherwise the code should work as shown below:

```js
const body = '{ "response" : "Not latest version of file, update not performed" }';

console.log("returned data1 " + body);
// returns: returned data1 "{'response' : 'Not latest version of file, update not performed'}"

var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
var valueReturned = jsonBody["response"];
console.log("logs: " + valueReturned);
// returns: logs: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

A hacky and unreliable method if you have to deal with your `body` as is would be to manually transform it into JSON format and then parse it:

```js
const body = `"{'response' : 'Not latest version of file, update not performed'}"`;
const formattedBody = body
  .slice(1, body.length - 1)
  .replace(/'/g, '"');
const obj = JSON.parse(formattedBody);
console.log(obj.response);
```